# Discord.py(Change bot's text color)

Tags: python, colors, bots, discord.py

I have searched the web but found no answer.

I created an embed for my discord bot and i know how to set the color of the bar on the left but how can i change the color of the text the bot sends?

Comment: Don't quote me on that but as far I know that's not possible? Something people use is syntax highlighting. But that's the only thing I can imagine right now.

Comment: I know about syntax highlighting but that only works when a user types a message using the syntax but when i put it in my bot's code it doesn't work. How can put it in my code so the bot types using the syntax?

Comment: check my answer, I've updated it to include example code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only solution I've been able to find for this (have had the same question before) was using syntax highlighting

````
```css
green text
```
````

You can find a list at this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/matthewzring/9f7bbfd102003963f9be7dbcf7d40e51#syntax-highlighting)

Hope it helps, I don't know about any other solution to really "color" texts without using syntax highlighting.

UPDATE:
Regarding comment from OP.

This was a way I've been able to include it into an embed.

````py
async def test(ctx, *args):
    retStr = str("""```css\nThis is some colored Text```""")
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Random test")
    embed.add_field(name="Name field can't be colored as it seems",value=retStr)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
````

produced this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/KyaP17K.png]

Without embed:

````py
async def test(ctx, *args):
    retStr = str("""```css\nThis is some colored Text```""")
    await ctx.send(retStr)
````

Produced this:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/SWi4owj.png]

It is important to write a new line `\n` after the language you choose for syntax highlighting otherwise it doesn't recognize it language declaration

Comment: This is the only way to do it. Note that you cannot set a custom color but have to relly on predefined colors for language you've selected, in this example #859900 (solarized green) for CSS. This way you have only 8 colors to choose from.

Comment: Thanks Vulpix, You answered my question well. The \n was all i need to make the syntax work with my bot. I added it and it works! Thanks!

Comment: The gist link is dead. Do you have a working link?

Comment: @Yolomep the closest I've found while asking google would be this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/8lev3t/discord_colored_text_with_code_markup_guide/) post. Hope it helps.

Comment: @YolomepYolo https://gist.github.com/matthewzring/9f7bbfd102003963f9be7dbcf7d40e51#syntax-highlighting