# How to change the text color in a code block ? - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, codeblocks

````
help = discord.Embed(description="```-@ = discord.user\n-() = required argument\n-[] = optional argument```",color=colour)
````

I want to change the color of the text in the code block that you can see in the description. Can somebody help me pls?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py(Change bot's text color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550163/discord-pychange-bots-text-color)

Comment: the problem is the \n after the discord.user per example, that you can see in the description when i tried it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

````py
help = discord.Embed(description="```diff\n-@ = discord.user\n-() = required argument\n-[] = optional argument```")
````

- the diff there specifies that the code is in the diff format which makes text after "-" look red and text after "+" look green. and maybe that's what you want, there are [other languages](https://gist.github.com/matthewzring/9f7bbfd102003963f9be7dbcf7d40e51#code-blocks)
- discord.Embed does not take any color parameter