# How to make discord bot send colored text from shell terminal using webhook

Tags: bash, discord, webhooks

```
webhook=https://discord.com/api/webhooks/abc123
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"content":"'"some message"'"}' $webhook
```

This is just a simple bash script that is used to send a message to discord using webhook. But is there a way to send colored text to discord? I know we can type in colored text on discord but how to send it from terminal? To be more clear, how to make the discord bot send colored text?

Comment: how do you want the result to look like? could you post a discord screenshot?

Comment: @battlmonstr like this but instead of default white text, I want it to be red or green: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlOLd.jpg

Comment: Or this could work too but I can't figure out how to do it in bash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550163/discord-pychange-bots-text-color/55550242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One hacky solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550163/discord-pychange-bots-text-color/55550242) - https://gist.github.com/matthewzring/9f7bbfd102003963f9be7dbcf7d40e51#syntax-highlighting

is based on syntax highlighting colors.

You can try that in Discord UI.

If you post a message like this:

````
```diff
+ line 1 asdasd
+ line 2 qwqwe
```
````

it should be green (has to contain "+" at the beginning of each line)

If you post a message like this:

````
```diff
- line 3 asdasd
- line 4 qwqwe
```
````

it will be red (has to contain "-" at the beginning of each line)

In shell you need to use double quotes around the message ( `-d "..."` ), escape quotes and back-ticks inside with a back-slash like `\"`, and use `\n` to separate lines:

```
-d "{\"content\": \"\`\`\`diff\n+ green\n\`\`\`\"}"
```

Answer (score -1):

The above didnt work for me.

````````
Send-DiscordNotification -message "```````diff
-Your text here.``````` "
````````

Worked for me. But I was using a webhook thru powershell.

I could't find any info on this online and chatGPT couldn't crack this either saying the webhook couldnt process the discord color codes. Hope someone finds this and it helps them out. PEACE.